# Merge all cells to one cell and separate with comma

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I use Google Sheets, and I want to get data and create one new cell.

**Example:**

I have 300 rows and 4 columns, like:

```
1|3|2|4

5|7|6|8

9|11|10|12

...

297|299|298|300
```

and one cell that I need in result:

1,3,2,4,5,7,6,8,9,11,10,12...297,299,298,300

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:D),,999^99)),,999^99)), " ", ", ")
```

[image: 0]

### ______________________________________________________

but if you want just numbers from 1 - 300 in CSV then:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(", ", ROW(A1:A300)))
```

Comment: bro, you are god

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Textjoin`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,A2:D)
```